# SQL server 2000 trace Flags

Tags: sql-server, trace, flags

On fixing an issue we are having with our backups I am following instructions where it is telling me to add the Trace Flag -g384. This is all good but I am not sure what this perameter actually does. I have had a quick google but have come up with nothing. Does anyone know what this perameter does or affects.

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you mixed some points...

Check [SQL Server Service Startup Options description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213799%28SQL.80%29.aspx) for details about command line parameters: -g (memory allocation) and -T (trace flags)

Comment: Thanks this cleans it up I will also now question the rest of the instucktions as they stated -g as a trace flag.